# How can I get a specific value from function?

Tags: python, function, return

So my question is: if I have a function that looks like this:

```
def function():
    x = 2 + 3
    y = x + 2
    return x, y
```

And I need to use an x from this function, but I don't need the y. How can I choose which value it returns.

PS. I can't change the code in the first function

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the function, it will always return both. But if you're interested in only `x`, you can assign the output tuple to two separate variables, and essentially ignore the `y` argument by assigning it to an arbitrary variable and forget about it

```
x, _ = function()

>>> print(x)
5
```

Another way would be to select only the first value in the tuple:

```
x = function()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

for example if you need the y, you can do this:

```
_, y = function()
```

or to get x:

```
x, _ = function()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function():
    x = 2 + 3
    y = x + 2
    return x, y

x, y = function()

print(x)
```

Hope that solved your problem